# How to get selectbox values and prices when user select a option in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example this hotel is 3 rooms:

```
<div id="hotel_room">
<select name="room_1" price="30" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 
<select name="room_2" price="40" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 
<select name="room_3" price="50"  multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

And other hotel is 4 rooms:

```
<div id="hotel_room">
<select name="room_1" price="30" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 
<select name="room_2" price="40" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 
<select name="room_3" price="50"  multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 
<select name="room_3" price="50"  multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

how can I get the users `selected` , `price`, `value` when a selection happened using jquery.

Comment: You have to add an explanation as to what the problem is, we're not psychic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code, maybe it will help you.

```js
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
 $('select').each(function(index) {
 console.log( $(this).attr('name') + ': price=' + $(this).attr('price') + ' selected option: ' + $(this).val() );
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hotel_room">
<select name="room_1" price="30" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 
<select name="room_2" price="40" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 
<select name="room_3" price="50"  multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 
<button id="button1">Click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can get all `needed` data when a `selection`.refer the working demo.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

</style>

<body>

<div id="hotel_room">
<select name="room_1" price="30" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 
<select name="room_2" price="40" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 
<select name="room_3" price="50"  multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">option 1</option>
      <option value="2">option 2</option>
      <option value="3">option 3</option>
      <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select> 

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

$("div#hotel_room select").click(function(){
 
 var getTheName = $(this).attr('name');
 var getThePrice = $(this).attr('price');
 var getTheValue = $(this).val();
 alert("NAME :----> "+getTheName +"    PRICE :-----> "+getThePrice +"   VALUE :-----> "+getTheValue);


});




</script>
</body>

</html>
```

hope this will help to you.